# Generic Haskell 'stringy' functions, Or: Where is lines :: IsString a => a -> [a]?

Tags: string, haskell, text

I'm searching for the inverse of the `unlines` function in `Data.String.Combinators`, `unlines` joins lines by appending newlines:

`unlines :: (Monoid s, IsString s) => [s] -> s`

The inverse of `unlines` should be `lines`, it splits a stringlike object on newlines:

`lines :: IsString s => s -> [s]`

An extensive search on [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and [hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/), also variations of `split`, `splitOn` etc. returns nothing. The naming of the function `unlines` even hints at the existence of its inverse `lines`. All `Data.String`, `Data.Text`, `Data.ByteString` etc. have a `lines` function, but no generic implementation seems to exist.

**It strikes me as odd that such a function should not exist. Are there any fundamental reasons for that?**

*Background:* Since `String` is still widely used, even though everybody (?) knows that it shouldn't be in almost all cases, I thought it would be good to replace my own `String->String`, and similar, functions by `IsString s => s -> s` or `(IsString s, Monoid s) => s -> s`. That way at least I don't contribute to a bias towards `String` while still allowing `String` for ease of use.

#### Update

It's clear to me, now, that the `IsString` typeclass, offering only `fromString`, is not sufficient for such a `lines` function. So the question morphs into: What properties are needed and what typeclass, if any, 'encapsulates' them?

Comment: The `IsString` class is not intended to represent 'string like objects' - its purpose is only to allow overloading of string literals. Any type for which there is a finite representation (even of just a subset of the type) can have a sensible instance of `IsString`. In my opinion, the author of `string-combinators` is not using `IsString` correctly; there is absolutely no guarantee or even convention that `IsString` and `Monoid` agree (i.e. `fromString (a + b) = fromString a + fromString b` and `fromString 0 = 0`) - without this fact those functions are not going to have reasonable behaviour.

Comment: This problem might be more appropriate to solve with a backpack-style module, rather than a typeclass.

Comment: One reason you might *not* wish to do this is that if `OverloadedStrings` is on (common, depending on the codebase), then your user's literals will all require type annotations

Answer (score 5):

`IsString a` only provides a conversion from `String` to `a`. This makes writing a meaningful `lines` unfeasible, in general.

For instance, here's a trivial case.

```
data T = T

instance IsString T where
   fromString _ = T
instance Monoid T where
   mempty = T
   mappend _ _ = T
```

We can't really define `lines :: T -> [T]`: the only possible (non bottom) result of that function is a list of the form `[T,T,T,...,T]` which is hardly useful, since it is completely unrelated to the input of `fromString`.

If possible, I'd suggest to use a more rich type class to allow for a `lines` function.